# How to make counter button

Tags: android, eclipse

Can someone tell me how to make a button to count how many times it has been clicked so that it will show up in statics activity. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `onCreate()`.

```
int count=0;
bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(youactivity.this, "You pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        count++;
    }
});
```

This code has a counter variable initialised to 0 and each time you click the button, the counter is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

Also, In button, you can attach the main activity 
using [View.setOnClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) - Used to call `onClick()` when the button is clicked.